# Locating phone inside airport without beacons

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, location, uuid

Use case scenario:  Customer inside a large space/building (say an Airport or could a university campus, hospital, anything) has ordered food online (website? ..or would a Anroid/iOS be necessary so that we can extract device data such as a UUID?) using his own phone or tablet, to be delivered where he is.

But how can we locate exactly where he is?  ..and I don't mean just in the room.  If he is sitting at a table, to be able to find him....or rather find his device which chair it is at.

What would the requirements be to achieve this if the building had no beacons?   Would UUIDs work?  How could the device be found?  I guess it would not be practical to install beacons all over the place eg. under seats, etc.

...and perhaps even create some sort of app for guiding the delivery person to where the customer is. ...just like a sat nav for cars, but within a large buidling.  I realise that this latter part is a seperate question so please perhaps responding to this bit seperately.

I look forward to your suggestions and ideas.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

They have an answer at many airports already-  tablets on each table and they order through the tablet.  Each tablet knows its table number and sends it with the order.

If you don't want to provide tablets at all the possible locations-  then the answer is beacons.  You want to know where a device is in a 2d field with very high accuracy.  Wifi location is too uncertain, you can be off by 100m.  GPS- if they enable it, and if its accurate indoors, and if the airport doesn't scramble it for security then its accurate to 10m or so, which is ok but not good enough to get food to a table.  That leaves you with needing a short range location finder.  Which is basically beacons.

A UUID won't help.  Great, you can now uniquely identify the device-  it gives you know info on where it is.  To do that you need to compare yourself to a known point.  That requires a known point(s) and a way of measuring how far from it you are and your direction from it.  Which requires you to be able to detect it somehow by it giving off a signal.  Which is a beacon.

Comment: Also [WiFi-RTT](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-rtt) should be considered if supporting hardware is available.

Comment: @MorrisonChang It can possibly work, but that's basically a beacon itself-  its just a beacon based on wifi instead of BLE.

Comment: I agree, but searching on 'android/ios location beacon' is more likely to bring up BLE beacon technology than the newer 802.11mc support which OP may not be aware of.

Comment: I used airports as an example.  The question is not specific about airports and whether they need this or not.  It could be a factory, a hospital, a university campus, anything.     But just to clarify the ordering would take place from the user's device.  Not from a pre-installed one like tablets in cases installed at airports.

So the question is...can this be done without beacons?  I gather from your response that the answer is no.  Is that right?  Or is there perhaps a way?

Comment: Then you need beacons.  There's no other solution.  Also a website won't work, you'd need a native app to be able to access the  signal data you need, whether the beacon is BLE or wifi-rtt